# Extending module but keep no-overwrite template map

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3, laminas

I was looking for how to re-use my User module across other projects.
As I have custom features for each my clients, I decided to create:

1. One generic *UserModule* to be packaging
2. One extend-module called *UserCustom*

UserModule has the following views: login and add (for register).
UserCustom is extending Module.php and no more.

```
<?php
namespace UserCustom;

use Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Users\Module as UserModule;

class Module extends UserModule
{

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }
```

Now, imagine that I want to change ONLY login view to add a logo.

I do not understand how can I overwrite specific view files and keep the others.
With my current config, I must to overwrite every view that UserModule has (overwrite to new file location or even vendor).

I've declared the following code to login new view file:
UserCustom module.config.php:

```
'view_manager' => [
    'template_map' => [
        'user/login' => __DIR__ . '/../view/user-custom/new_login.phtml',
```

But, when I go to /add page, its seems like I need to declare every view.
Laminas\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "user/add"; resolver could not resolve to a file

My UserModule has a

```
'template_path_stack' => [
 'user' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
],
```

but I do not know if its helps me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To override any action view file you've to understand the basic functionality of how Laminas search a view file. To understand this you can view the configuration [here](https://github.com/laminas/laminas-mvc-skeleton/blob/2.0.x/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L49) and I'll explain it below.

```
return [
  'template_stack' => [  
       // template stack means where will all the view files of every controller and its action will be found.
  ],
  'template_map' => [
     // the default map would be as follows
     // 'ModuleName/ControllerName/ActionName' => 'actual path of file.' 
    'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
  ],
];
```

To override an action template file you've defined it in your module.config.php file like below.

```
return [
  'template_map' => [
    'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/mymodulename/mycontrollername/myactionname.phtml',
  ];
```

I hope I've answered your question.

Comment: So do I need to define EVERY path file in template_map first?

Comment: Yes, when you're overriding a template file you've to define which ones you want to override. If you want to override only the login template. You'll only give template_map of the login template. If you've like forgot, log in, register etc. You've to override the template map for all three of them. This is for overriding only. When writing a module you don't have to specify a template map only a template stack will suffice. **Also, I don't know how to override all templates of a module in one line of code. Maybe there is an option. But I don't know that one.** Thanks!